# Where exactly is the mistake in my duplication check code?

Tags: c++, duplicates

I was trying to make a duplicate check in c++ in a programming problem I got interested in. In short, it prompts the user to input a number more than equal to 0, and less than equal to the number of input numbers the user decides.
When this program works, it is supposed to return the duplicate numbers, but when I tested it, it only prints out random strings of letters.

```
int arrCheck;
for(arrCheck=0; arrCheck<=arrLimit-1; arrCheck++)
{
    if(arr[abs(checkarr[arrCheck])]>=0)
    {
        arr[abs(checkarr[arrCheck])]=-arr[abs(checkarr[arrCheck])];
    }
    else
    {
       cout<<arr[arrCheck]+" "<<endl ;
    }
}
```

ArrLimit is the number limit the user decides. The numbers in array checkArr[] is one bigger than its arr[] counterparts.

For clarification, the idea that in the array of n numbers, it can only be filled with numbers between 0 and n-1 inclusive is a part of the problem.

Update: anything below is the code lines preceding the code section above.

```
int main()

{
    cout<<"How many numbers do you want?";
    int arrLimit;
    cin>>arrLimit;
    int arr[arrLimit-1];
    int checkarr[arrLimit-1];

    int arrValue;
    int arrLoop=0;
    while(arrLoop<=arrLimit-1)
    {
        cout<<"Insert numbers (non negative integers only)";
        cin>>arrValue;
        if(arrValue<=arrLimit-1)
        {
            arr[arrLoop]=arrValue;
            checkarr[arrLoop]=arrValue+1;
        }
        else
        {
            cout<<"Invalid, try again!"<<endl;
            continue;
        }
        arrLoop+=1;
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Read up on how to provide a [mcve].   Without a sample of code that can be used to recreate the problem (in particular, how are `arr` and `checkarr` defined and how are they initialised?) and a clear description of the behaviour you seek, nobody can help you.

Comment: When you declare an array, you specify its size, not its largest index.

Comment: `cin>>arrLimit; int arr[arrLimit-1];` this is not standard C++.

Comment: ```cout<<arr[arrCheck]+" "<<endl ;``` - what you're actually doing here is taking a pointer to string " " and moving it by arr[arrCheck] bytes.. What you've actually wanted is:
```cout << arr[arrCheck] << " " << endl;```

Answer (score 1):

Let's do a worked example

```
How many numbers do you want?
2
```

Now arrlimit == 2, arr has size 1, checkarr has size 1

```
Insert numbers (non negative integers only)
1
```

Now arrvalue == 1, arrLoop == 0, arr[0] == 1, checkarr[0] == 2

```
Insert numbers (non negative integers only)
1
```

Now arrvalue == 1, arrLoop == 1, arr[1] == 1, checkarr[1] == 2. There last two are an error because `arr` and `checkarr` are size 1 so `arr[1]` and `checkarr[1]` are illegal. But lets ignore that and carry on.

Now we're in the final loop, arrcheck == 0 so `arr[abs(checkarr[arrCheck])] >= 0` ==> `arr[abs(checkarr[0])] >= 0` ==> `arr[abs(2)] >= 0` ==> `arr[2] >= 0`, and again arr[2] is illegal because arr has size only 1.

And so on, basically your code makes a great many array out of bounds accesses. But to be honest even without those, I'm not sure that the algorithm is correct.